# dtypes change for Large datasets in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, scipy

So I am using pandas to create a dataframe from a CSV file and I have a column which is of dtype datetime. This works as expected with smaller datasets. If the dataset is large the operations i perform on this column change it to an object instead of datatime. Is there any way to preserve the dtypes? I tried using iloc or ix with the dataframe but that didnt work. Below is some of my code and where the problem lies.

```
twitterDataFrame['CreatedAt'] = twitterDataFrame['CreatedAt'].map(lambda x: pandas.to_datetime(x))
twitterDataFrame['CreatedAtForCalculations'] = twitterDataFrame['CreatedAt']
```

The problem appears on Line 3 in the next set of code. It complains that `tweetsByEachUser['CreatedAtForCalculations'].first()` and `tweetsByEachUser['CreatedAtForCalculations'].last()` are strings and that it cannot compute the negation of strings.

```
# Frequency of Tweets
twitterDataFrame = twitterDataFrame.set_index(['CreatedAt'])
tweetsByEachUser = twitterDataFrame.groupby('UserID')
numberOfHoursBetweenFirstAndLastTweet = (tweetsByEachUser['CreatedAtForCalculations'].first() -     tweetsByEachUser['CreatedAtForCalculations'].last()).astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

I have tried

```
twitterDataFrame.ix['CreatedAtForCalculations':].dtypes
```

but this does not work either. Would anyone know a solution for this?

Sample of data from df.info

```
  Int64Index: 21836 entries, 0 to 21835
  Data columns (total 17 columns):
  CreatedAt                   21836 non-null object
  ActualTweet                 21836 non-null object
  InReplyToStatusID           21836 non-null bool
  InReplyToUserID             21836 non-null bool
  UserID                      21836 non-null object
  RetweetCount                21836 non-null object
  FavouriteCount              21836 non-null object
  Hashtags                    21836 non-null bool
  URL                         21836 non-null bool
  MediaURL                    21836 non-null bool
  MediaType                   21836 non-null object
  UserMentionID               21836 non-null bool
  PossiblySensitive           21836 non-null object
  Language                    21836 non-null object
  Classifier                  21836 non-null object
  TweetLength                 21836 non-null object
  CreatedAtForCalculations    21836 non-null object
  dtypes: bool(6), object(11)None
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Firstly just do this to convert to datetime: `twitterDataFrame['CreatedAt'] = pandas.to_datetime(twitterDataFrame['CreatedAt'])`, secondly you can convert to datetime when reading the csv : `pandas.read_csv('my_csv.csv', parse_dates=[x])` where x is the ordinal number of the datetime column e.g. 0 for first. Thirdly, post data and reproducible code that demoes your problem, is that line even valid code? On my toy data I get error `TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'`

Comment: Ignore last remark about valid code, I didn't see that you had performed a groupby operation, if the conversion was successful then your code should've worked. Does `twitterDataFrame.dtypes` show column `CreatedAt` as `datetime64[ns]` after the conversion?

Comment: Thank You. Just double checked that and it seems like even the first two lines of code - where i set createdAT to datetime initially make the column an object as opposed to datetime64[ns]. I also tried using the options you gave above to change to datetime with no luck. However with a smaller dataset this works as expected.

Comment: It's possible that there is invalid data which the conversion cannot deal with, I'd check the data and see if you can find any incorrect values. What version of numpy and pandas are you using?

Comment: Pandas verison : 0.14.0 Numpy : 1.8.1

Comment: It should work so I you need to post your data for others to look at and also see if you can find the errant data

Comment: Well theres around 50k data at the moment which might be hard to manually look through. Would you know a way to test if data is valid and if so to proceed?

Comment: show a sample of the data and ``df.info()``

Comment: Thanks. Question updated. It infact converts everything to Object apart from booleans. Int64 etc are converted to objects.